# Create a Reg-ex which accept numbers and + as the first character

Tags: java, regex

I am trying to create a regex where I get the results as `+82 11-1111-1111` in java. The first number should start with `+82`  with a space then it should get accept only `11` or `12` or `13` and the n the rest of the numbers can accept numbers between `0-9`

For eg.

1. `+82 12-2234-3344`
2. `+82 13-1234-5678`
3. `+82 11-3456-4567`

Please help

Comment: Or `\\+82 1[1-3](?:-\\d{4}){2}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should try something like this:

```java
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class PhoneNumberRegex {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(validate("+82 12-2234-3344"));
        System.out.println(validate("+82 13-1234-5678"));
        System.out.println(validate("+82 11-3456-4567"));
        System.out.println(validate("+82 31-3456-4567"));
        System.out.println(validate("+82 31-34564-4567"));
    }
    
    private static boolean validate(String input) {
        Pattern argPattern = Pattern.compile("\\+82 (12|13|11)(?:-\\d{4}){2}");
        Matcher matcher = argPattern.matcher(input);
        return matcher.matches();
    }
}
```

When I run this, I get this output:

```sh
src : $ java PhoneNumberRegex 
true
true
true
false
false
```